# How to pass the output of select query as column list to another select query in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to pass the output of a select query as column list to another select query.

```
select ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT distinct COLUMN_NAME::VARCHAR(50)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='products' AND 
COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('code') ), ', ');
```

The above query will give the output as like give below,

```
array_to_string      
---------------------------  
name, price, manufacturer
```

Now I need to pass this output as column list to another select query. So I tried like this,

```
select ( select ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT distinct
COLUMN_NAME::VARCHAR(50) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE
TABLE_NAME='products' AND  COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('code') ), ', ') ) 
from products;
```

But it is not working properly. It gives the output like this:

```
          ?column?          
 ---------------------------  
 name, price, manufacturer  
 name, price, manufacturer  
 name, price, manufacturer
```

Instead of,

```
       name       | price | manufacturer 
 -----------------+-------+--------------  
 Hard drive       |   240 |            5  
 Memory           |   120 |            6  
 ZIP drive        |   150 |            4
```

So, how can I solve this?

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for this. This can't be done with plain SQL because the structure of the result of a query needs to be known **before** that query is actually executed.